# Django many to many relationship only shows on one model in the admin

Tags: python, django

I’m new to python and django and have set a many:many relationship between the `Subscriber` and `Tag` classes (i.e. one subscriber can have many tags, and one tag can have many subscribers). In the django admin panel, viewing a tag successfully shows the connected subscribers as follows:

[image]

However, viewing a subscriber does not show the tags they’re associated with:

[image]

It’s like the many:many relationship is not shown on both sides. I’ve read some other similar django posts creating inlines and functions etc, but to no avail - and I want the tags to show only on the individual subscriber page rather than a column in the table before clicking on an individual subscriber.

How can I get the tags to show on the individual subscriber pages? I tried with inlines but to no avail.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Account


class Subscriber(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    # tags: many to many field, with later option of users being able to define custom tags
    # tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=true) # cannot uncomment, otherwise error: "NameError: name 'Tag' is not defined" - but already has many:many relationship - just not showing in django admin
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    list_display = ('first_name', 'email', 'date_joined', 'verified')


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(Subscriber, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from subscribers import models


# class TagInline(admin.TabularInline):
#     model = models.Tag.subscribers.through
#     extra = 0
# unneeded - individual tag pages already show their subscribers


# class SubscriberInline(admin.TabularInline):
#     model = models.Subscriber.tags.through # ERROR: attributeError: type object 'Subscriber' has no attribute 'tags'


@admin.register(models.Subscriber)
class SubscriberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("first_name", "email",
                    "date_joined", "verified", "account")


@admin.register(models.Tag)
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = models.Subscriber
    # inlines = [TagInline, ] # inlines unneeded - individual tag pages already show their subscribers
    list_display = ("name", )
```

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: have you tried adding inlines = [TagInline, ] to the SubscriberAdmin class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the tag field appear just on Subscriber page, move the Tag class **before** the Subscriber class, doing this will avoid triggering the NameError. Remove the subscribers field on Tag class to avoid creating another relationship and uncomment the tags field on Subscriber class. You don't need to use inlines or anything else.

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Account

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Subscriber(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    # tags: many to many field, with later option of users being able to define custom tags
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=true) # cannot uncomment, otherwise error: "NameError: name 'Tag' is not defined" - but already has many:many relationship - just not showing in django admin
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

list_display = ('first_name', 'email', 'date_joined', 'verified')
```